# solving knapsack dynamic programming debugging

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I tried to solve the classical [knapsap problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) myself. But I am getting a wrong answer as `108`. Could you help me to figure out what I have done wrong. Here I am using `recursion`.

Weight limit is 10

answer is 5+3+2 ==> 25+15+14=54

```
public class KnapSack {
public static int[] weight={6,5,4,3,2};
public static int[] value={12,25,24,15,14};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(c(0,0,10));
}

public static int c(int currentElement,int currentValue,int currentReamainder){

    int p = 0;
    if(currentReamainder<=0) return currentValue;

    for(int i=currentElement;i<weight.length;i++){
        if(currentReamainder<weight[i]) return currentValue;
        p = Math.max(value[i]+c(i+1,currentValue+value[i],currentReamainder-weight[i]),c(i+1,currentValue,currentReamainder))
    }

    return p;
}

}
```

**Update:**
What should I do to print the weights of the optimum solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is this line

```
 p=Math.max(value[i]+c(i+1,currentValue+value[i],currentReamainder-weight[i]),c(i+1,currentValue,currentReamainder));
```

it should be

```
 int val = Math.max(value[i]+c(i+1,currentValue+value[i],currentReamainder-weight[i]),c(i+1,currentValue,currentReamainder));
 p = Math.max(val, p);
```

The last bug is when you both updating `currentValue` and return `p` at the same time, so imagine the last call, when the function return `currentValue`, plus the last `value[i]` in each step, so your result is double

So , your function should be (notice I have removed the `currentValue` parameter, which is not necessary):

```
public static int c(int currentElement,int currentReamainder){

    int p = 0;
    if(currentReamainder<=0) return 0;

    for(int i=currentElement;i<weight.length;i++){
        if(currentReamainder<weight[i]) break;//This line is not valid, only when the weight array is sorted(ascending order)
        int val = Math.max(value[i]+c(i+1,currentReamainder-weight[i]),c(i+1,currentReamainder));
        p = Math.max(val, p);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Still my answer is incorrect. It gives 108 which is the double of the correct answer.

Comment: Edited as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I will roll back. Thank you.

Comment: Got your answer Thank you.

Comment: **Update:** What should I do to print the weights of the optimum solution ?